# PDF acroforms not being copied properly in itext

Tags: java, forms, pdf, itext

So I have this PDF form and set the fields to it:

```
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest + i + ".pdf"));
            AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
            form.setField("name", "Bruno Lowagie");
            form.setField("adress", "ADDRESS");
            form.setField("dates", "January 1, 2010");
            form.setField("titles", "blah blah blah");
            stamper.close();
            reader.close();
```

However when i try to copy all the files to a another file, Fields only appear on focus of the fields, pelase help

```
             Document document = new Document();
         PdfCopy pcf = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(ALL_CUSTOMER_FILE));
         pcf.setMergeFields();
         document.open();


            int documentnumber = 0;
            for (String input : inputs) {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
                documentnumber++;
                renameFields(reader, documentnumber);
                pcf.addDocument(reader);
            }
            pcf.close();
           document.close();
```

Comment: I just ran a sample and the fields retained their value. Could you tell/show us what you're doing in your renameFields() method? Also, what version are you using?

Comment: @melt321 Please inspect (or provide for inspection) your `src` PDF file: Is its **NeedAppearances** flag set to false? And which version of iText exactly are your using? Recently there have been certain changes and follow-up issues concerning the processing of the **NeedAppearances** flag value.

Comment: @mkl has diagnosed the problem correctly. We also noticed this problem and this will be fixed in next week's release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who are experiencing the same issue (currently using itext 5.4.4), I was able to solve this by setting setAppearance true for the AcroFrom and setFormFlattening to true:

```
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    form.setGenerateAppearances(true);
    form.setField("name", "Bruno Lowagie" + i);
    form.setField("adress", "ADDRESS");
    form.setField("dates", "January 1, 2010");
    form.setField("titles", "blah blah blah");
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
```